# How to get error from backend with axios?

Tags: react-redux, axios, jsx, mern

I'm trying to display an error I recieve in my backend to the user in my JSX frontend file.

This is the initial call from frontend

```
dispatch(createGoal({ values }))
```

Goalslice, directly called from JSX:

```
export const createGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  'goals/create',
  async (goalData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
      return await goalService.createGoal(goalData, token)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)
```

Goalservice, directly called from goalslice:

```
const createGoal = async (goalData, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  }

  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, goalData, config)

  return response.data
}
```

Goalcontroller, my backend:

```
const setGoal = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const goals = await Goal.find({ user: req.user.id })
  var count = Object.keys(goals).length
  if(count >2){
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('Maximum of 3 trackers per user')
  }
  if (!req.body.values) { //if this isnt there. check if the body is there.
    res.status(400) //This is an error
    throw new Error('Please add a date field') //this is express error handler
  }
  console.log(req.body.values.dates)
  const goal = await Goal.create({
    values: req.body.values.dates, //get from request body
    permit: req.body.values.permits,
    numpermit: req.body.values.num,
    user: req.user.id,
  })

  res.status(200).json(goal)
})
```

I want to display this error:

```
throw new Error('Maximum of 3 trackers per user')
```

I tried a try/catch method, but I'm very new to this and I feel like i'm missing a very key point in how it all fits together.

This is my custom error handler if it helps:

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => { //overwrite express error handler, next to handle any new req
  const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 500 //500 is server error. conditional

  res.status(statusCode)

  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack, //gives additional info if in development mode : is else
  })
}

module.exports = { //export for others to use
  errorHandler,
}
```